# Exercise 1_2 multiple console outputs. I would like to reduce the number of console output statements

Tags: c++

Please could we examine the below code for anyway to put all console output in one statements?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main( )
 {  //print("") in Python
   cout<<"Hello " "everybody!"<<endl;
   cout<<"My name is AK."<<endl;
   cout<<"Goodbye."<<endl;
   cout<<""<<endl;

   //Poem
   cout<<"Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!"<<endl;
   cout<<"How I wonder what you're at?"<<endl;
   cout<<"Up above the world you fly,"<<endl;
   cout<<"Like a tea-tray in the sky."<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just use `'\n'` literals inside the text you want to output, or even better [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: i did this  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( )
{   //print("Hello World")
    //Displays Hello World on the screen
    // Short form with string literals

    string Intro = "Hello everybody!"<<endl
    "My name is AK".\n
    "Goodbye."\n
    \n
    "Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!"\n
    "How I wonder what you're at"?\n
    "Up above the world you fly,"\n
    "Like a tea-tray in the sky.";

    cout<< Intro<<end1;
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Scope

This is really just limited to style and code formatting.

### Two (almost) substantive points

- You should get in the habbit of **not**:

```
using namespace std;
```

It can get you into name-clash issues later, as you progress.

- You should be aware that `std::endl` flushes the stream buffer. This is often unnecessary, unwanted and can be slow if used in a tight loop. You should use `'\n'` for most situations. If you are worried about
  platform specific line-ending, don't be. `'\n'` adapts, just like
  `std::endl`.

### Code formatting

- Install [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) or similar to help you with formatting.

All I did was to integrate your `endl` into the strings and hit "auto-clang-format" and I got this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello everybody!\n"
            << "My name is AK.\n"
            << "Goodbye.\n"
            << "\n"

            // Poem
            << "Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!\n"
            << "How I wonder what you're at?\n"
            << "Up above the world you fly,\n"
            << "Like a tea-tray in the sky.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Which is "good enough for me". Clang format is very tunable, and I have it configured to something which works for me, and my team, in 99% of cases. So we don't spend time fighting the formatting of the code.

The above style with "one streaming operator" `<<` at the beginning of each line is what we use most of the time. It makes sense when you have literals interspersed with variables and/or function calls.

For this very specific (and rather atypical?) case, you could, as someone else pointed out, also just stream it all as one continuous literal. C++ allows you stop/start string literals like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello everybody!\n"
               "My name is AK.\n"
               "Goodbye.\n"
               "\n"

               // Poem
               "Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!\n"
               "How I wonder what you're at?\n"
               "Up above the world you fly,\n"
               "Like a tea-tray in the sky.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why not using raw string literals for the whole text? Just to preserve the comments?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, as it is all one string, you could in this case. Have added that.

Comment: Are you sure what _raw string literal_ means?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ
It's not something I get exited about, but yes I do. And I don't see the point here.  It's just messy. but that's entirely subjective.

Comment: I am sorry for the messy cod. I hope i can soon learn how to write cleaner code. Thank you for the string literals direction. I found out why you used R"x as it outputs raw data. You guys are the best.

Comment: @IEatBagels To be fair to him, he did below.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Well, my bad ahah

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in single statements using raw string literals:

```
#include <iostream>

 int main( )
 {  //print("") in Python
   std::cout << 
R"x(Hello everybody!    
My name is AK.
Goodbye.
)x";

   //Poem
   std::cout<<
R"x(Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!
How I wonder what you're at?
Up above the world you fly,
Like a tea-tray in the sky.
)x";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: counter nitpick: don't use `namespace std`. That's 2 statements, not one. And it looks messy. IMHO. ;-) Indentation is totally broken if you used that in a class or nested block.

Comment: Thank you very much good people. I have just started learning so my apologies that it looks like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to mark/upvote both answers as very useful but it won't let me. What have i done wrong because both answers are correct?

Comment: @Megadon.cyber You can upvote both, but not accept both I think. Don't sweat it.

Comment: I generally advise against multi-lines raw string literals because they mess up with indentation. The parser doesn't care, but the human reader does.